# Grep and xargs: File name too long

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to delete all the files that *do not* start with `__`. This

```
ls | grep -v "__" | xargs -0 rm
```

Yields `: File name too long`. Any help?

EDIT:

```
ls | grep -v "__" | awk '{print("rm \42"$0"\42")}' | /bin/bash
```

solves the problem, but I'd like to know why the first is not correct. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take out the `-0` argument and it will fix this problem. the `-0` arg to xargs says that the items in the input list are null terminated. You aren't doing that, you are passing lines terminated by an `\n` character.